# trying to find out how to reformat JSON response and reformat the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is a doozie.

I've got the following .json formatted file:

```
"response": {
    "tickets": [
        {
            "alias": "Lower Box 122",
            "curr_price": 16.0,
            "quantity": 2,
            "seats": "17,18",
        },
        {
            "alias": "Lower Box 122",
            "curr_price": 8.0,
            "quantity": 5,
            "seats": "1,2,3,4,5",
        },
        {
            "alias": "Lower Box 122",
            "curr_price": 14.0,
            "quantity": 7,
            "seats": "6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
        },
        {
            "alias": "Lower Box 123",
            "curr_price": 16.0,
            "quantity": 2,
            "seats": "17,18",
        },
        {
            "alias": "Lower Box 123",
            "curr_price": 8.0,
            "quantity": 5,
            "seats": "1,2,3,4,5",
        },
        {
            "alias": "Lower Box 123",
            "curr_price": 14.0,
            "quantity": 7,
            "seats": "6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
        }
                ]
            }
```

I'm trying to get this output:

```
Lower Box 122,
quantity: 15,
seats: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,17,18,
price: 8-16

Lower Box 123,
quantity: 15,
seats: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,17,18,
price: 8-16
```

Unfortunately, reformatting the original JSON file isn't possible. I've got to deal with the format that it's currently.

I don't necessarily need it in a .json format again. Spitting out text to a page will be just fine. Can anyone point me to a utility that does just this? or a script that will bang this out?

difficulty: javascript only.

I want to thank everyone that had an answer - hopefully this will come in handy for others.

Comment: Javascript with jQuery presumably, as you tagged jQuery.

Comment: How are you getting this file in to the browser, a `$.getJSON()` call?

Comment: yup. getJSON - I could use getScript also

Comment: Your quantity is wrong - 2 + 5 + 7 = 14

Comment: math is hard.. never been my strong point :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little bit of work required in order to merge those ticket types.

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var responses = {};

       $.getJSON('responsefile.json', function(data) {
           $.each(data.response.tickets, function(index, cTicket) {
               var cSeats = cTicket.seats.split(/,/);

               if (responses[cTicket.alias] == undefined) {
                   responses[cTicket.alias] = { alias: cTicket.alias,
                                                price: { min: cTicket.curr_price, max: cTicket.curr_price },
                                                quantity: cTicket.quantity,
                                                seats: cSeats };
               } else {
                   var cResponse = responses[cTicket.alias];

                   $.each(cSeats, function(i, cSeatNumber) {
                       if ($.inArray(cSeatNumber, cResponse.seats) == -1) {
                           $.merge(cResponse.seats, [cSeatNumber]);
                       }
                   });

                   cResponse.seats.sort(function(a, b) {
                       return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
                   });

                   cResponse.quantity = responses[cTicket.alias].seats.length;
                   cResponse.price.min = (cTicket.curr_price < cResponse.price.min ? cTicket.curr_price : cResponse.price.min);
                   cResponse.price.max = (cTicket.curr_price > cResponse.price.max ? cTicket.curr_price : cResponse.price.max);

                   responses[cTicket.alias] = cResponse;
               }
           });

           var responseSet = [];
           $.each(responses, function(index, cResponse) {
               responseSet.push(cResponse);
           });
           responseSet.sort(function(rA, rB) {
               return (rA.alias < rB.alias ? -1 : (rA.alias > rB.alias ? 1 : 0));
           });

           processResponses(responseSet);
       });

   });
})(jQuery);
```

---

As you requested a method of writing out the responses, I have slightly altered the code above to call a function to do on exit.  Just adapt this function below to point to the right place.

```
(function($) {
    function processResponses(responses) {
        var responseText = '';
        var csv = "alias,quantity,seats,price\n";

        $.each(responses, function(index, cResponse) {
            responseText = responseText
                           + cResponse.alias + ",\n"
                           + "quantity: " + cResponse.quantity + ",\n"
                           + "seats: " + cResponse.seats.join(',') + ",\n"
                           + "price: " + cResponse.price.min + (cResponse.price.min == cResponse.price.max ? '' : '-' + cResponse.price.max) + "\n";
            csv = csv
                  + cResponse.alias + ","
                  + cResponse.quantity + ","
                  + cResponse.seats.join(' ') + ","
                  + cResponse.price.min + (cResponse.price.min == cResponse.price.max ? '' : '-' + cResponse.price.max) + "\n";
        });

        $('#text-output-location').text(responseText);
        $('#csv-output-location').text(csv);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Note the need to space-separate the seat values in the CSV output, as comma separating them would require a lot of escaping and reduce clarity.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p5QUb/**

**NB.** The demo version has a few modifications to allow the AJAX to take place on jsfiddle.net, which requires special handling, also slight changes to the output to add line breaks.

Comment: this is good, but i couldn't figure out how to write it into a div, or list item, or whatever...

Comment: @jake: I have expanded my answer with a routine to do that for you.

Comment: Orbling - this is great! Beer for you too!  However - this is one issues with ` responses.sort(function(rA,rB) {
               return (rA.alias < rB.alias ? -1 : (rA.alias > rB.alias ? 1 : 0));
           });`  it keeps throwing an error. When i remove that function, it starts to work.. any idea? Googling for it didn't turn anything up.

Comment: Ah yes, keep forgetting the `sort()` method is for arrays only, not object lists.  Easy enough solution, I will modify.

Comment: I've been up and down this code, but it's still falling short. If I use your original version, I can get the seats, quantity, etc to print, but the sections are still "undefined". Can I talk you into taking another look at it ?

Comment: Here is the file hosted on my server: [link](http://heykoolaid.com/sorted_values.html)

Comment: @jake: Apologies for the delay, was at work - I downloaded and edited your version.  The code above has been corrected, I had not actually run the code at all, just typed it in to here - was relying on you to do the debugging, but I misinterpreted a couple of functions in jQuery when I updated things, which mucked things up.  The above should work.

Comment: this is perfect! Thanks Orbling! How does one vote for the right answer? I hope that this comes in helpful for anyone else!

Comment: @jake: Glad it helped, could well help others lots of interesting techniques shown in the answers here. You already accepted david's answer, with the tick; but you can vote up any answers that helped you by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer.

Comment: @Orbling: I'm working on jqgrid. Would appreciate your help on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581897/jqgrid-rendering-javascript-file-with-the-column-model. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var response = {"tickets":[{"alias":"Lower Box 122","curr_price":16.0,"quantity":2,"seats":"17,18",},{"alias":"Lower Box 122","curr_price":8.0,"quantity":5,"seats":"1,2,3,4,5",},{"alias":"Lower Box 122","curr_price":14.0,"quantity":7,"seats":"6,7,8,9,10,11,12",},{"alias":"Lower Box 123","curr_price":16.0,"quantity":2,"seats":"17,18",},{"alias":"Lower Box 123","curr_price":8.0,"quantity":5,"seats":"1,2,3,4,5",},{"alias":"Lower Box 123","curr_price":14.0,"quantity":7,"seats":"6,7,8,9,10,11,12",}]};

        var seats = new Array();
        var alias = "";
        var quantity;
        var min_price = 999999;
        var max_price = -1;


        $.each(response.tickets, function(key, value){


            if(value.alias != alias)
            {
                if(alias != "")
                {
                    seats = seats.sort(function(a,b){ return parseInt(a) > parseInt(b); });
                    alert(alias + "\ncurr_price: " + min_price + "-" + max_price + "\nquantity: " + quantity + "\nseats: " + seats);
                }

                alias = value.alias;
                quantity = 0;
                min_price = 999999;
                max_price = -1;
                seats = new Array();
            }

            if(value.curr_price < min_price)
            {
                min_price = value.curr_price;
            }

            if(value.curr_price > max_price)
            {
                max_price = value.curr_price;
            }

            $.each(value.seats.split(","), function(key, value){


                if($.inArray(value, seats) < 0)
                {
                    seats.push(parseInt(value));
                }
            });

            quantity += parseInt(value.quantity);
        });

        //Call again for last one
        seats = seats.sort(function(a,b){ return parseInt(a) > parseInt(b); });
        alert(alias + "\ncurr_price: " + min_price + "-" + max_price + "\nquantity: " + quantity + "\nseats: " + seats);
    });



</script>
```

Comment: You could also add some code to detect whether the min and max price are the same and only display 1 or the other rather than e.g. 16-16

Comment: bingo! How can i buy you a beer?

Comment: @jake - mmm beer :-) no need just remember to mark the answer correct ;-)

Comment: So, I've been playing around with this script, and unfortunately, the page never finishes loading after the script has executed. Any ideas?

Comment: That could be for any number of issues - are you using Firebug or Chrome? are there any JS errors?

Comment: Firebug - even with console.log it tells me nothing, and it's not throwing any errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to include [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) you could use the `reduce`/`lfold` method.
I gave it a shot, but I suspect it could be neatened up a little:

```
_.reduce(x.response.tickets, function(memo, obj){
    memo[obj.alias] = memo[obj.alias] || {quantity:0, seats:[]};
    memo[obj.alias].maxPrice =
        Math.max(memo[obj.alias].maxPrice || obj.curr_price, obj.curr_price);
    memo[obj.alias].minPrice =
        Math.min(memo[obj.alias].minPrice || obj.curr_price, obj.curr_price);
    memo[obj.alias].quantity += obj.quantity;
    memo[obj.alias].seats =
        memo[obj.alias].seats.concat(_.map(obj.seats.split(","), function(v){
            return parseInt(v,10);
        }));
    memo[obj.alias].seats.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
    return memo;
}, {})
```

which leaves you with:

```
{
    "Lower Box 122": {
        "quantity": 14,
        "seats": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18],
        "maxPrice": 16,
        "minPrice": 8
    },
    "Lower Box 123": {
        "quantity": 14,
        "seats": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18],
        "maxPrice": 16,
        "minPrice": 8
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you'd prefer the result to be an array of objects rather than the hash, you can transform it like this (assuming `var k` is the result of the fold above):

```
_.keys(k).map(function(alias){
    k[alias].alias = alias;
    return k[alias];
})
```

Comment: this is pretty awesome! I've been messing around with this, but unsure how to retrieve the results from a getJSON call, store the json into a variable, then access the variable from the _underscore script. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @david: Nice, jQuery is missing one of the folds, wrote an extension for it on here at some point, can't find it now obviously as the search sucks.  Have yet to use underscore.

Comment: @jake, when you do the getJSON call, you give it a function reference to use as a callback, and the object should be the first parameter to that function. It is already an object, not a JSON string, so you don't need to do anythign to it. Inside that callback you can either run the underscore.js 'script' there, or you can save the original object and use it later. (In my example 'x' is the object, you might call it 'data' or something)

Comment: @david: Not quite sure why I have yet to use Underscore.js, coming from a functional background (primary reason for using jQuery), I will come to love Underscore I think.  Linked the reference to the library in your answer, hope you don't mind, must publicise it.

Comment: @Orbling to tell you the truth, this is the first time I have ever used it to do anything. Seems quite powerful though.

Comment: @david: Well the `_.reduce()` function is very well implemented, you are using `_.map()` as well, which is more or less the same as any other.  The main difference in our code is verbosity, partly that is down to Underscore, which is good, partly down to your using `||` effectively and partly down to less whitespace. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The following will spit it out in the right format for you:

```
var obj = { /* your JSON goes here */ };

for (var i=0; i<obj.response.tickets.length; i++) {
  document.write(obj.response.tickets[i].alias + ",<br/>");
  document.write("quantity: " + obj.response.tickets[i].quantity + ",<br/>");
  document.write("seats: " + obj.response.tickets[i].seats + ",<br/>");
  document.write("price: " + obj.response.tickets[i].curr_price + "<br/><br/>");
}
```

Comment: That does not merge the seats or create price ranges.

Comment: A very good point! That'll teach me not to read the whole question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you'd parse that sample output though, since you're separating fields with commas, but one of your values has commas in it, there's an ambiguity there.

Assuming your JSON is parsed into an object called `data`, you could just use jQuery:

```
jQuery.map(data.response.tickets, function(elt) {
    var fields = [];
    fields.push(elt.alias);
    fields.push("quantity:" + String(elt.quantity));
    fields.push("price:" + String(elt.curr_price));
    fields.push("seats:" + elt.seats);
    return fields.join(",\r\n");
}).join("\r\n\r\n");
```